# black screen except launcher and menu bar parallel ubuntu on mac

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, mac

After messing with lots of things, I end up on black screen every where. No thing is rendered except launcher and menu bar. Tried to reinstall parallel tools, installing and uninstalling and updating and upgrading the nvidia driver, lightdm and whatever I find as solution on net. Nothing is helping at all. The screen shot of what I have is as below:

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

It is only supported for the Mac operating system, not anywhere on the Mac Computer. You'll have to install Mac OS X again if you wanna get Parallels working. Yes, Mac is kind of based on Linux, but applications for Mac OS X won't run on Linux and applications from Linux won't run on Mac OS X.